# Can I install mate-panel following the procedure in the description?

Tags: wingpanel

I stumbled onto [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/337jqy/matepanel_top_bar_on_freya/) on Reddit, but while the question is really interesting none of the answers is of much help.

Has anybody tried installing it in Freya?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it does not work anymore.

```
This is possible in Luna but you can't do it in Freya because it depends on super-wingpanel:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/global-menu-elementaryos-luna/
The dev for super-wingpanel abandoned it so it won't run in Freya.
SeriouslyLaughing - On the reddit thread you've posted.
```

But the only way to be sure is to try it yourself. You could create a virtual machine with elementary OS to test it with, that way you don't harm your system.